# retrieve database value into applet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, applet

since last two days, i was trying to embed an applet into my webpage, applet will retrieve the database values and show it into combo box.

But, i got **AccessControlException** exception, when i'm trying to run my jsp page (in which i've embedded my applet). Now, i've the last option with me, which is, using 3-tier architecture to communicate the applet with database as i found on internet. Now, i don't know how to retrieve the value into applet from database using the Servlet as middle layer. Because, i'm unable to get the data from the database into my applet. Please help me. Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Usually database set up to accept connection only from localhost. That means you can connect to it only from servlet (or something else, but from server). Applet tries to connect to the db from client's ip but it's usually forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was indeed going totally the wrong path with writing JDBC in an Applet. The source code of the Applet is publicly visible to the enduser. The malicious enduser would be able to decompile it and see the DB name/password and/or edit it to change the SQL queries to do a `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` or any other bad things instead. Bye bye database.

You need to design and create a "Web Service" which listens on certain URLs only and returns the results in a common format like XML, JSON, CSV or whatever. Then your Applet has just to invoke exactly that URL by `URLConnection` and process the results. There are a lot of Java libraries to convert Java objects to XML/JSON/CSV format and vice versa. You can use the same library in the code of both the web service and applet.

Imagine that you're choosing JSON and thus using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert between Java and JSON, then you can basically do as follows in the Servlet which acts as a "Web Service":

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Just a basic example. In real, just retrieve data from DB.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("item1");
    list.add("item2");
    list.add("item3");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(list);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

this is obtainable as follows in the Applet:

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "servletURL");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");
List<String> list = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());
// ...
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is Gson and this typetoken, because i'm getting error here. :(

Comment: Don't blindly copypaste the code. Read the answer text as well, including all links. Those blueish words are not just decoration.

Comment: sorry...for my question..i'm very new for this. that's why i'm asking this type of question. last thing, how could i use this list into combo box of applet.

Comment: That's a different question which has got completely nothing to do with databases and applet-servlet communication. Just ask a new question wherein you ask how to show `List<String>` in `JComboBox`. All other details are irrelevant.